# Copy document library from one sitecollection to another using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library, ssom

copy the document library with metadata from one to another site collection using PowerShell

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )   
 {  
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell  
 }
  ######################## Set Execution Path ################################################  
 $scriptBase = split-path $SCRIPT:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent  
 Set-Location $scriptBase  
 ################################# End of Set Execution Path #################################
 $CurrentTime = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm 
 $res=Test-Path ".\log"
if($res -eq $false)
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\log"
}
$outputFilePath = ".\log\CopyLibrary_$CurrentTime.log"
############################# Move the library from source site collection to target Site Collection ########################
 function MoveLibrary()
 { 
    $srcSiteCollectionUrl=""
    $srcSubsiteUrl =""
    $srcLibraryTitle=""
    $tgtSiteCollectionUrl=""
    $tgtSubsiteUrl=""
    $tgtLibraryTitle=""
    # Get Source Site and verify exist or not  
    $sourceSite = Get-SPSite($srcSiteCollectionUrl) -ErrorAction Ignore   
    if($sourceSite)
    {
        #get source subsite
        $sourceSubSite = $sourceSite.OpenWeb($srcSubsiteUrl)  
        if($sourceSubSite)
        {
            #Get document library from the subsite and verify for exist
            $sourceLibrary = $sourceSubSite.Lists.TryGetList($srcLibraryTitle) 
            if($sourceLibrary)
            {    
                $contentTpeColl = $sourceLibrary.ContentTypes
            }
            else
            {
                Add-Content $outputFilePath "Active Library Doesnot exist in current site , provide proper library title" -PassThru 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Add-Content $outputFilePath "Please Provide proper Subsite Url" -PassThru 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Add-Content $outputFilePath "Please Provide proper active Site collection Url" -PassThru 
    }    
    # Get the target Context,Subsite and library
    $targetSite = Get-SPSite($tgtSiteCollectionUrl) -ErrorAction Ignore
    if($targetSite)
    {
        $targetSubSite = $targetSite.OpenWeb($tgtSubsiteUrl)
        if($targetSubSite)
        {
            if($sourceLibrary)
            {
                # Check and create target Library if doesnot exist
                $targetLibrary = $targetSubSite.Lists.TryGetList($tgtLibraryTitle)
                if(!$targetLibrary)
                {
                    $targetSubSite.Lists.Add($srcLibraryTitle,$srcLibraryTitle,101)
                    $targetLibrary = $targetSubSite.Lists.TryGetList($tgtLibraryTitle) 
                }
                $tSiteContentTypeColl = $targetSite.OpenWeb().AvailableContentTypes
                $sLibraryContentTypeColl = $sourceLibrary.ContentTypes
                if(!$targetLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled)
                {
                    $targetLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
                    $targetLibrary.Update()
                }
                # Add source library Content types to target library
                foreach($sContent in $sLibraryContentTypeColl)
                {
                    $sId = $tSiteContentTypeColl.BestMatch($sContent.Id)                  
                    if(!$targetLibrary.ContentTypes[$sContent.Name])
                    {
                            $targetLibrary.ContentTypes.Add($tSiteContentTypeColl[$sId])
                            $targetLibrary.Update()
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                continue
            }
        }
    } 
    $formsUrl = $sourceLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/"+ "Forms"
    $sLibUrlLength = $sourceLibrary.RootFolder.Url.length
    $sourceFolderCollection = $sourceLibrary.Folders|where {$_.Url -ne $formsUrl}
    #$tFolderUrl = $sourceLibrary.RootFolder.Url
    try
    {
        foreach($sourceFolder in $sourceFolderCollection)
        {           
            # append the compltre url of the library to create non existing folders
            $tFolderUrl = $targetSubSite.Url + "/" + $targetLibrary.RootFolder.Url 
            $tLibraryUrl =  $targetLibrary.RootFolder.Url                    
            $sFolders = $sourceFolder.Url.substring($sLibUrlLength).Split('/')
            $i=0
            while($i -lt ($sFolders.count-1))
            {
                if($sFolders[$i])
                {
                    $tFolderUrl = "$tFolderUrl/" + $sFolders[$i]
                }    
                #Increment the I variable in order to move forward through the folder structure
                $i++
            }            
            #verify folder exist in target Library ,if not creat new folder
            $tLibraryUrl = $targetLibrary.RootFolder.Url +  $sourceFolder.Url.substring($sLibUrlLength)
            if(!($targetLibrary.Folders | ? {$_.Url -eq $tLibraryUrl}))
            {
                $tFolder = $targetLibrary.Folders.Add($tFolderUrl,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder,$sourceFolder.Name)
                $tFolder.update()
                $sFolderItem = $sourceFolder.Folder.Item
                $tFolderItem = $tFolder.Folder.Item
                $sFolderFields = $sFolderItem.Fields |?{!($_.sealed)}
                # Update target File Metadata from source file metadata  
                foreach($sFolderField in $sFolderFields)
                {
                    if($sFolderField.ReadOnlyField -ne $true -and $sFolderField.Hidden -ne $true)
                    {
                        $tFolderItem[$sFolderField.InternalName] = $sFolderItem[$sFolderField.InternalName]
                    }
                }
                $tFolderItem["ContentTypeId"] = $sFolderItem.Item["ContentTypeId"]               
                $tFolderItem.Update()
                $tFolder.Update()
            }
            else
            {
                $tFolder = $targetLibrary.Folders | ? {$_.Url -eq $tLibraryUrl} 
            }
            $sFileCollection = $sourceFolder.Folder.Files
            foreach($sFile in $sFileCollection)
            {
                try
                {
                #Upload the file to target folder 
                $sBinary = $sFile.OpenBinary()
                $tFile = $tFolder.Folder.Files.Add($sFile.Name , $sBinary , $true) 
                $sItem = $sFile.Item
                $tItem = $tFile.Item
                $sFileFields = $sItem.Fields |?{!($_.sealed)}
                # Update target File Metadata from source file metadata  
                foreach($sField in $sFileFields)
                {
                    if($sField.ReadOnlyField -ne $true -and $sField.Hidden -ne $true)
                    {
                        $tItem[$sField.InternalName] = $sItem[$sField.InternalName]
                    }
                }
                $tItem["ContentTypeId"] = $sFile.Item["ContentTypeId"]               
                $tItem.Update()
                $tFile.Update()

                }
                catch [System.Exception] 
                { 
                    Add-Content $outputFilePath $_.Exception.ToString() -PassThru 
                    continue 
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    catch [System.Exception] 
    { 
        Add-Content $outputFilePath $_.Exception.ToString() -PassThru  
    }  
        #$sourceFolderCollection|where {$_.Url -ne $formsUrl}
       # $sourceFolderCollection
        #CheckAndCreateFolderStructure 
 } 
 MoveLibrary
```